# Why isn't the Perl symlink created when I supply the installusrbinperl option?

Tags: perl, compilation

The docs on the [compiling and install Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/INSTALL) say,

> By default, `Configure` will not try to link `/usr/bin/perl` to the current version of perl. You can turn on that behavior by running
>
> ```
> Configure -Dinstallusrbinperl
> ```

However, it doesn't seem to work that way: I've enabled that option and confirmed it worked,

```
# /usr/local/bin/perl5.33.7 -V | grep install
config_args='-des -Dusedevel -Dinstallusrbinperl -Dcc=gcc'
```

However, `command -v perl`, `which perl` and `locate perl | grep bin` show nothing named "perl" in the `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin` directories. However, there are executable (not-symlinks) there,

```
/ # ls /usr/local/bin/perl*
/usr/local/bin/perl5.33.7        /usr/local/bin/perlivp5.33.7
/usr/local/bin/perlbug5.33.7     /usr/local/bin/perlthanks5.33.7
/usr/local/bin/perldoc5.33.7
```

But that docs say this option will add a `perl` symlink, all I have are the actual files. If I check the result of my call to `Configure` stored in the generated `config.sh` file, I see,

```
grep installusr ./config.sh 
config_args='-des -Dusedevel -Dinstallusrbinperl -Dcc=gcc'
config_arg3='-Dinstallusrbinperl'
installusrbinperl='define'
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `/usr/local/bin/perl5.33.7 -V:versiononly` say?

Comment: `-Dusedevel` has an effect on both `installusrbinperl` (which you override) and `versiononly` (which you don't). So if `versiononly` is pertinent, this is probably the issue.  `-Dversiononly=undef`??

Comment: @ikegami thanks that worked! I needed `-Dversiononly=undef`. If you want to answer that I'll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `versiononly=undef`

In order to have this install Perl symlinks without versions you'll have to use

```
Configure -Dinstallusrbinperl -Dversiononly=undef
```

Comment: I believe this is only necessary when using `-Dusedevel`

Comment: right, `versiononly` defaults off, `usedevel` turns it on, but an explicit value overrides that.